# Flutter : image overflow

Tags: flutter, dart

can i solve this overflow when import big image ?
I am working on an interface project only and I want to solve this problem when importing a large image

change this :

[image: change this]

to this :

[image: this]

my code :

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff131517),
        appBar : AppBar(),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Container(child: Image.file(_image! , fit: BoxFit.contain , width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,)),
                Spacer(),
                Container(
                  height: 85,
                  color:Color(0xff1e1f23),
                  child: Center(
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: [],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain the height of the container the image is in (or of the image itself) like so:

```dart
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff131517),
        appBar : AppBar(),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.9,
                  child: Image.file(
                    _image!,
                     fit: BoxFit.contain,
                     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    )
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Container(
                  height: 85,
                  color:Color(0xff1e1f23),
                  child: Center(
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: [],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
```